# How do I convert from MMM-DD-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD in Excel for Mac 2019

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

I've found similar threads but they haven’t quite worked for what I’m trying to do.

Current data is in the form `MMM-DD-YYYY` within one cell, recognized by excel as ‘Number’ then sub category ‘general’.

Visually they look like ‘Nov 08, 2018’.

I want to convert the above to stay in one cell but display as: ‘20181108’.

I have 10,000 date entries to convert so trying to find a simple way to do this. Have been looking at right-click > format cells > custom then creating a new entry of `YYYY-MMM-DD;` but this doesn’t seem to change anything.

Comment: Have you just tried changing the format? If there isn't one that meets your criteria by default you can create custom formats.

Comment: assuming cell A3 is holding one of your dates, use the following formula and let us know the results =ISTEXT(A3)

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Search and Replace to remove any quotes or extra characters in the cells, making sure the content is "pure" dates.
2. Hold CTRL and hit 1; make sure the cells are set as "Date" and nothing else
3. Select one empty cell, type a single zero in it and press enter
4. Select the cell with the 0, hold CTRL and hit C
5. Select the date cells you have a problem with
6. From the Edit portion of the Ribbon, or from a menu: Select Edit >
   Paste Special
7. In the Dialog that appears; Select ADD, click OK.
8. Hold CTRL and hit 1 again
9. Select Custom (Excel) or "User defined" (LibreOffice) and type in YYYYMMDD in the custom format specifier box, click OK.
10. See any dates still not in the format you wish? Repeat from step 1 above.